# Is it a good idea to try and do dependency inversion in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

We want to rely on interfaces instead of concretes in our object orientated solutions however when you inject a service into an Angular component you usually use a concrete since after compilation the app is just javascript, and there are no interfaces in javascript.

I have just seen some code that solves this issue like so:

```
export const serviceProvider = new InjectionToken<CustomTypeCreatedUsingGenericsForComposition>('CustomTypeCreatedUsingGenericsForComposition');
```

and then in the module providers:

```
{
  provide: CustomTypeCreatedUsingGenericsForComposition,
  useClass: AnInstance,
}
```

and then in a component:

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(ResidentialKeysListBLLProvider)
    private residentialKeysListBLL: ResidentialKeysListBLL
) {}
```

Implementation is now decoupled from DI and to change the service you change useClass. The token essentially acts like a wrapper around being able to directly use an interface as a DI argument.

This seems great as we have basically achieved the dependency inversion principle in SOLID but we have added complexity for something that should be very specific anyway since it is provided at a module level. So does it actually help?

Comment: In my opinion, you're adding extra complexity of the sake of feeling warm and fuzzy about SOLID.  Remember, Typescript isn't C# or Java even thought it "feels" like it.  When you declare providers in a module you can already easily swap them out without creating all these tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use InjectionToken but in my opinion there is much better solution.

You can not inject interfaces in Angular DI, but **you can inject abstract classes**.

## Example

Simple interface:

```
export interface IVehicleService {
    doSomething(param1: string; param2: string);
}
```

Simple abstract class:

```
export abstract class VehicleService implements IVehicleService {
    abstract doSomething(param1: string; param2: string);
}
```

Concrete class:

```
@Injectable()
export class MazdaVehicleService extends VehicleService {
    doSomething(param1: string; param2: string) {...}
}
```

DI rule:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
       { provide: VehicleService, useClass: MazdaVehicleService }
    ]
})
```